# Which is performs better? Many connections making few queries/sec, or a few connections making many queries/sec?

Tags: mysql

We're trying to start up a pretty simple app with simple queries, but a high volume. We're using node.js for our server. We're considering using mysql as our db backend, but trying to figure out the performance on connections.

Which would perform better (assuming all queries are equal size)?

- 1 connection making 100 queries per second
- 10 connections making 10 queries per second
- 100 connections making 1 query per second

Comment: Openning a connection itself is time / cpu consumming... that said, I think 1 connection will perform better.

Comment: What about trying them both and measuring the times with a test database with a substantial data size? I can think of arguments for each approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 connection using 100 queries/second would be more performant since the server doesn't have the overhead of creating/destroying multiple sockets.

Since each query is of the same size, we only have to worry about the act of connecting.

Further, since each connection takes (presumably) the same amount of time to create, using less of them takes less time.